# FitNesse Maven Classpath plugin (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, maven, plugins, classpath, fitnesse

I followed the instructions the README of https://github.com/amolenaar/fitnesse-maven-classpath.

I have a fitnesse-standalone.jar and in the same directory, i have the below plugin.properties file:

```
Theme=bootstrap
SymbolTypes=fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
05/27/2014  06:19 PM         6,309,648 fitnesse-standalone.jar
05/27/2014  06:20 PM    <DIR>          FitNesseRoot
05/27/2014  06:24 PM                15 plugins.properties
```

I executed the below:

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar
```

And I got the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" fitnesse.PluginException: Unable to load class fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType
    at fitnesse.PluginsLoader.forName(PluginsLoader.java:191)
    at fitnesse.PluginsLoader.loadSymbolTypes(PluginsLoader.java:123)
    at fitnesse.ContextConfigurator.makeFitNesseContext(ContextConfigurator.java:135)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:55)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:48)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.main(FitNesseMain.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at fitnesse.PluginsLoader.forName(PluginsLoader.java:189)
    ... 5 more
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? How do I "install" the fitnesse plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a **plugins** folder in the same dir as fitnesse-standalone.jar.
2. Build and compile the plugin via mvn
3. Copy the jar(s) in your plugin folder
4. Add the string "SymbolTypes=fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType" in your plugins.properties file
5. Run fitnesse-standalone.jar

Comment: I have the very same problem and this solution did not work.

I've tried it with fitnesse-standalone-20150814.jar as well as with  fitnesse-standalone-20150114.jar and maven-classpath-plugin-1.9.jar

also java -cp "fitnesse-standalone-xxx.jar;maven-classpath-plugin-1.9.jar" fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain fails, missing the other class:
org.codehouse.plexus.PlexusContainerException

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You need to copy in the jar-with-dependencies

Comment: @DJ180 I copied the jar-with-dependencies, but it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry just to answer my own question there in case its any use to anyone, when you say "jar-with-dependencies"  - you mean downloading [this version](http://fimt-nexus-repository.fmrco.com/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/fitnesse/plugins/maven-classpath-plugin/1.9/maven-classpath-plugin-1.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar) of the jar and putting it in the plugins folder, doing this resolved the issue for me